# How can I two-way sync Windows Contacts with Gmail Contacts

Tags: sync, google-sync, gmail-contacts

I'm using Windows Mail (which uses the windows contact store behind the scenes) to connect to the gmail imap server.  I would like to have my gmail contacts available to me when using Mail.

How can I set up a two-way sync to automatically sync the Windows Contact store with Gmail Contacts?

*Please note: there seems to be a lot of resources for how to sync to outlook, these solutions wouldn't work for me as I'm not using outlook.*

Comment: The Best Way to Keep Outlook Express Address Book Automatically Synchronized with Google Contacts: http://androidnaut.blogspot.com/2011/01/best-way-to-keep-outlook-express.html

Comment: Anyone know how to import to Google Contacts from Windows Contacts? http://superuser.com/questions/902349/how-to-import-windows-contacts-to-google-contacts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know if you don't have a Google Apps account, there is no active bidirectional sync. You could just set up an [imap Gmail account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/setting-up-gmail-imap-support-for-windows-vista-mail/) in Windows Mail, but there's no (official) tool to sync the changes you make locally back to Gmail.

You refer to the Outlook post, but I think I they concluded something the same there.

I recommended [using GcalDaemon](http://gcaldaemon.sourceforge.net/features.html) there, but I think it only gives you access to your addressbook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mail and GMail both understand the concept of a CSV, so I would export my GMail contacts to a CSV then import the CSV in Windows Mail.

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified, a one time import is not what I'm looking for.  I updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for a two-way automatic sync so the two stores stay updated.

Comment: Good luck with that then.