# How to import Windows Contacts to Google Contacts?

Tags: windows-7, contacts, google-contacts, windows-contacts

I would like to import my Windows Contacts to Google Contacts. How can I do that?

Windows Contacts are files with `.contact` extensions. Google Contacts accepts `.csv` and `.vcf` I believe (one at a time).

Comment: I have the opposite question how do I import google contacts to windows .contacts files?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your Contacts folder. To do so, type **Contacts** or **shell:contacts** in the Start search box, and press {ENTER}
2. Select all files in the Contacts folder.
3. Click "Export" button in the Toolbar.
4. Select whichever format (.vcf or .csv) you'd like them exported to, and set the destination folder.

The resulting file can be imported to Google Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it via CSV files

[Export your contacts to a CSV file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-contacts-625336d9-14e2-49a8-909d-02648989e4f0), probably easiest via your mail client (like Outlook). If you don't have Outlook, you can download Live Mail for free.

Then you can import the CSV file into the Google contacts.